# Transforming a Tkinter entry to variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I can't get an entry value and make it a usable variable for the rest of my code, this part is only able to create a variable z, but it ends up empty, this is my forth try on a different approach without good result.

The `entry.get()` returns nothing, I need it to return a string.

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.initialize()        

    def initialize(self):

        self.btn1 = Button(self, text = 'Ok', command=retrieve_input)
        self.btn1.grid()


def retrieve_input():
    print 'Input value => %s' %entry.get()     

root = Tk()
root.title('Teste')
root.geometry('200x100')
entry = Entry(root)
entry.grid(column=0,row=0)


entry.focus()                                    
entry.bind('<Return>', (lambda event: retrieve_input()))  
z=entry.get()

app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine. Anything I type in the entry box shows up in the terminal when I click Ok or press Return.

Comment: `z` is always empty because you're setting it approximately a millisecond after the Entry was created - there has been no opportunity for the user to type anything into it yet!

Comment: @Novel Do you mean the print part, that's true to me to, but the variable is still nowhere to be found

Comment: @jasonharper what do you mean? How can I change that?

Comment: I mean that you need to call `entry.get()` *after* the user has typed something in it, rather than before.  You've done it right in `retrieve_input()`, since that's called in response to the user clicking a button.

Comment: The entry contents changes ... a variable cannot change. You need to use the method entry.get() in every place you want the current value; not a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call:

```
z = entry.get()
```

*whenever* you want `z` to be what's written in `entry`. As in replace `retrieve_input` with:

```
def retrieve_input():
    global z
    z = entry.get()
    print 'Input value => %s' %z
```

for example.

Comment: @BryanOakley True. But they're not _assigning_ it to `z`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a variable with the name as what's written in `entry` you could populate a `variables` dictionary like in below code:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def add_variable():
    global variables, entry
    variables[entry.get()] = None
    print(variables)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    variables = dict()
    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Add variable...", command=add_variable)
    entry.pack()
    button.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```